# SOLR search with plus(+) within field query search criteria. Escaping doent seems to be working in this case

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to do SOLR search for text like "C++" which contains "+" within it.
tried to escape the "+" but even thought its not fetching the results. Instead its matches for only "C".
Is there a way to include "+" as a search criteria and get the exact result ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which special characters need escaping in a solr query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914956/which-special-characters-need-escaping-in-a-solr-query)

Comment: There is no solution on how to escape "+" special character within field query. I know that special character needs to be escaped but even though for + , its not working.

Comment: I'm no Lucene expert by any standard, but the linked question has an accepted answer pointing to the Lucene docs, which have a section about escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax.

Comment: Thanks @zyndor, but that doesnt resolve my issue.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of the field? If the field definition splits / replaces on non-alphanumeric characters, escaping won't matter.